# Why does $a=b=0$ iff $a = 0$ and $b = 0$

Tags: logic

I am a freshman in college, and I have a question about one of my courses.

In logic class, we are doing a demonstration to prove the following hypothesis:
$(a, b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
Let's say
$$
f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, 
\quad x \to ax^2+b \quad \;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, 
\quad f(x) = 0 \implies a=b=0
$$

To prove it, we use the contrapositive ($P \to Q \iff \neg Q \to \neg P$), but our teacher simplifies $a=b=0$ by $a=0$ and $b=0$ so that we replace it in the contrapositive with $a≠0$ and $b≠0$ (because its $\neg Q$).

But why does $a=b=0$ not imply $a=b$. Because according to my teacher, the negation of $a=b=0$ is $a \neq 0$ or $b \neq 0$, so potentially $a=b=4$, and I don't understand how that can be the negation of $a=b=0$ since $a=b$.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You need to put the definition of $f(x)$ in your question, and the connection between $a,b,$ and $f.$ Also some advice on terminology: A hypothesis is something which is assumed, one doesn't prove it. Maybe you should call it a "proposition" or "theorem" or the like.

Comment: $a=b=0$ means $a=b\land b=0$. Equality is transitive.

Comment: $a=b=0$ is an abuse of notation. $=$ is a binary relation, not a ternary relation, and they formally cannot be chained like this. But it is usually read by definition as $a=b$ and $b=0.$

Comment: I did rewrite my question, forgot to define f, a and b, but was my professor wrong ?

Comment: "My teacher said the negation of $a=b=0$ is $a \ne 0$ and $b \ne 0$" - your teacher is wrong. The negation would be $a \ne 0$ *or* $b \ne 0$.

Comment: it was indeed, my bad but why

Comment: If $a=b=4$, would you argue that $a=b=0$ could be true?

Comment: I feel so stupid... thanks !
But should I in the future decompose a=b=0 to a=0 and b=0 in any context ?

Comment: You could alternatively decompose it, as Thomas Andrews did above, into "$a=b$ and $b=0$" which would give an alternative, but logically equivalent, form for the negation.  In logic, this might be preferable since it doesn't assume transitivity of $=$, but in mathematics, you typically would want to write it as the simplest form possible, so "$a=0$ and $b=0$" would be my go-to.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a=b$ is true if $a=b=0$, $\neg(a = b = 0)$ is true if $\neg(a = b)$. However, the converse of the first statement isn't true, so the converse of the second is not necessarily true.